# Using XDebug with Dreamweaver CS5 (Writing PHP)

Tags: php, dreamweaver, xdebug

I usually use Netbeans for PHP development, but have recently had to move to Dreamweaver CS5 at work.

Is it possible to get XDebug working with Dreamweaver CS5? It was incredibly simple to integrate it with Netbeans but don't know where to start with Dreamweaver!

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is a free IDE, why you just don't convince your boss about installing it - mention something about productivity - that will get his attention. I use Dreamweaver CS5 when I need to deal with the view part of my MVC app, but for code, no way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope you can't

Netbeans is so much better than DW regarding PHP